# My .htaccess redirect to https produces a 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I want my webserver to redirect all http requests to https.
So I set up my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

The redirect seems to work, but when I enter _http://example.com/test/ it redirects to _https://example.com/httpdocs/test/ which produces a 404 error.
If i go to _https://example.com/test/ directly, everything works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank Simone,
your solution didn't work for me.

I found that

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use `HTTP_HOST`, not `SERVER_NAME`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

See https://serverfault.com/questions/570288/is-it-bad-to-redirect-http-to-https

Also, make sure you don't have other rules that conflict with this one. You may want to promote this one as the first rule (given it has the `L` flag).

Comment: The leading slash is not required in the rewrite pattern.